# Как вывести значение переменной с помощью jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

js

```
var a="World";



$(function(){
    $('.redStyle').bind('click', function(){
        $(".layer").append(' <p>a</p>'); // где 'а' переменная
    });

});
```

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
  
</head>
<body>
    
    <button class="redStyle">Нажать</button>
  
    <div  class="layer" >
     <h2 id="h">Teкст </h2>
    </div>
     

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-o88AwQnZB+VDvE9tvIXrMQaPlFFSUTR+nldQm1LuPXQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> 
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Так:

```
$(".layer").append(' <p>' + a + '</p>');
```

Это простая конкатенация.

Или так:

```
$(".layer").append(`<p>${a}</p>`);
```

Второй способ описан тут:

https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: или `$(".layer").append($("<p>", {html: a}))`